Cross-machine communication fails between Docker containers using Discovery Server
I'm trying to set up ROS 2 Humble communication between Docker containers on different machines using Fast DDS Discovery Server, but the listener never receives messages from the talker.
Machine 1 (IP: 192.168.98.107): Running Discovery Server and Talker in Docker containers
Machine 2: Running Listener in Docker container
All containers using the basic ros:humble image with demo_nodes_cpp installed
The setup works perfectly when running natively (without Docker) on both machines:
Machine 1, Terminal 1:
fastdds discovery --server-id 0 --port 11888

Machine 1, Terminal 2:
export ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER="192.168.98.107:11888"
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker

Machine 2:
export ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER="192.168.98.107:11888"
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener

However, when using Docker with port mapping (avoiding network_mode: host), the listener never receives messages. Here's my Docker configuration:
Machine 1 docker-compose.yml:
services:
  discovery-server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "11888:11888/udp"
      - "7400-9500:7400-9500/udp"
    command: /bin/bash -c "source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash && fastdds discovery --server-id 0 -p 11888"
  talker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER=192.168.98.107:11888
    ports:
      - "7400-9500:7400-9500/udp"
    command: /bin/bash -c "source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash && ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker"

Machine 2 docker-compose.yml:
services:
  listener:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER=192.168.98.107:11888
    ports:
      - "7400-9500:7400-9500/udp"
    command: /bin/bash -c "source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash && ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener"

Dockerfile (same on both machines):
FROM ros:humble
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y ros-humble-demo-nodes-cpp fastdds-tools && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

What I've verified:

Both machines can ping each other
No firewall blocking the ports
Port 11888 is open and accessible from Machine 2
The setup works when using network_mode: host (but I need to avoid using host networking)

What am I missing to get ROS 2 communication working between Docker containers on different machines without using host networking?
